# Hive : How to avoid creating empty partitions in hive?

Tags: hive, partitioning

I have a table in hive which is partitioned on date basis. Sometimes I don't get data for some dates but still it creates empty partitions in hive warehouse dir. Is it possible to avoid creating empty partitions in hive?

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the problem even if it creates empty partitions?

Comment: It creates a lot of partitions directories in hive warehouse dir. If i have to scan the directories using shell command then it prints the empty partitions also.

Comment: An empty partition can be actually useful, it tells you that a certain date was processed, but had no data, vs not have being processed/completed at all.

Comment: What is the load method? Insert overwrite partition does not create empty partitions. Most probably you are using load inpath partition method and passing empty file? In such case you should just check the filesize>0 (excluding headers) before loading.